# Resource for C++

Tags: c++

It has been a long time since I've used C++. I want to start programming in C++ again but I am looking for a particular resource and wondering if anyone here has any good references. I am looking for a book, web tutorial, video...whatever that teaches you C++ while you're building an application. So, for example, a book might start the book by starting the application.. and so on. Does anyone have a good reference? Thanks

Comment: One thing you didn't specify which may affect the answers you get: which OS are you targeting with your development?  C++ without the OS libraries is kind of like _pure_ functional programming--interesting but not much practical use.

Comment: This has got to be a dup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A great free tutorial is the [C++ language tutorial at cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) and its [other resources](http://cplusplus.com/).

You could also checkout popular C++ books like: The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup or Effective C++ by Scott Meyers,

Comment: +1, but I'd remove /doc/tutorial from that URL - cplusplus.com is a handy resource to keep bookmarked all the time.

Answer (score 4):

I find [The C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/index.html) to be one of the best sites for C++ advice.  It is not oriented toward beginners, but then, neither is the C++ language. :)

I'll also second Brian's recommendation of "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers.  That is one of the best C++ books you can read.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exact answer to your request, but if you're going to have to deal with maintaining existing C++ code and/or if you learn well by example, I've found [How Not to Program in C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886411956) a very handy book. The sample "bad" programs are easy to understand but you're forced to find the bug in the code.

I was in a similar situation. I had learned using C++ in school but had spent most of my career with Perl/Python/C#/Bash and had forgotten my "basics".